# Why (actually) does it take me so long to make 1000 cubes?

Tags: python, scripting

Creating 1000's of objects is slower than I thought it should be. Based on a [suggestion here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/33596) it could be related to name collision checking so I thought I would look into it. Here is some data, and the script I used. As a reference, I also did a simple name comparison between all pairs of objects using an extremely sloowwwww loop in python. That is almost 100 times faster than the creation (which is happening in C, right?) So something else is going on.

Both of these times are clearly proportional to n^2, so it does seem to be checking the new shape against all the others. The times don't change much when I use icospheres (80 faces) instead of cubes(6 faces), so it's based on objects, not faces. That rules out some kinds of checking.

My question is, first, why (actually) is it so slow, and second, how can I create thousands of objects (e.g. cubes) in a script, without waiting minutes each time I tweak some parameter, while still seeing all of them once it's done. I'm using 2.74.

NOTE: I did some spot checking by running the loop only once, or over and over with the same nxy, and there does not appear to be contamination of the measurements due to memory issues (see my comments about garbage collection in the script).

[image: time to make a thousand cubes]

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
import time

wxy = 15.0
sx, sy, sz = 0.9, 0.9, 0.2
t_create_list, t_check_list = [], []
n_create_list, n_check_list, n_same_list = [], [], []
nxy_list = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40]
listlen = len(nxy_list)

for ii, nxy in enumerate(nxy_list):
    rcube = 0.5 * wxy / float(nxy)
    q = 0.5 * wxy * (1. - 1. / float(nxy))
    xyc = np.linspace(-q, q, nxy)
    XC, YC = np.meshgrid(xyc, xyc)
    ZC = np.zeros_like(XC)
    centers = zip(XC.flatten(), YC.flatten(), ZC.flatten())

    start = time.clock()
    for ic, center in enumerate(centers):
        ok = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(radius=rcube, location=center)
        ao = bpy.context.active_object
        ao.scale = (sx, sy, sz)
    stop = time.clock()
    time_to_create = stop - start

    so = bpy.context.selectable_objects
    number = len(so)

    same, count = 0, 0
    start = time.clock()
    for i in range(number):  #very sloowwwww way to compare names
        for j in range(i, number):
            count += 1
            if so[i].name == so[j].name:
                same += 1
    stop = time.clock()
    time_to_check = stop - start
    t_create_list.append(time_to_create)
    t_check_list.append(time_to_check)
    n_create_list.append(number)
    n_check_list.append(count)
    n_same_list.append(same)

    for thing in so:
        thing.select = True
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=True)
    # but can I invoke garbage collection inside this loop?
    # for example, can I somehow do a save .blend which should cause garbage collection?

    print("number ", ii+1, " of ", listlen)

t_create_list = [round(thing,4) for thing in t_create_list]
t_check_list =  [round(thing,4) for thing in t_check_list]

lists = [n_create_list, t_create_list, n_check_list,
         t_check_list, n_same_list]

save = np.array(lists[0],dtype='float')
for thing in lists[1:]:
    save = np.vstack((save, thing))
np.save("check_it_out", save)
```

Comment: I think your suspicion is correct. It compares against all other object's names to rule out duplicates. I wish I could give you credible source from the source code, maybe later I'll dig into it. EDIT: going against the mentioned answer, it could be faster - if one edits the blender source code - it could have a runtime of `O(n*log(n))` instead of `O(n^2)`, a significant improvement. Might want to open a bugreport

Comment: It would be great to have a facility to switch off collision checks (for new non-primitive objects - which allow you to specify an object name), in the same way one can switch off undo for parts of the script.

Comment: So @WorldSEnder my point is a very very slow python script can do a simple name comparison 100 time FASTER than the creation. There is something else happening. I think there is a factor of 100 or 1000 or more issue here - the coefficient in front of the n^2. Also  `O(n*log(n))`  binary search may not help if the problem is something else. This factor is just HUGE! (edited comment)

Comment: Also note that you are doing `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add` which is an `.ops` , really meant to be triggered by UI only it does additional scene updates too (besides name collision checking). The pure creation of an object using `data.objects.new(object_name, object_mesh)` in a loop like that is most likely faster but still noticably slow

Comment: Just being curious: how is it with copying a cube all the time instead of creating a new one?

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators

Comment: @uhoh a more fair speed test would be this https://gist.github.com/zeffii/8efcc53976ed4165d7c7

Comment: As I found in [the tests I done](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14846/935) dupliverts are much faster than creating one cube at a time.

Comment: OK thanks @sambler. I will look into these and try these alternate methods. In one application I'll have maybe only four or five groups of cubes (imagine 500 blue cubes, 500 red cubes, etc.) as in [this example](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34609/5334)  but in another case, maybe 1000 unique satellites or asteroids as in [this example](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/33993/5334).

Comment: Thanks @zeffii, I think you have already cautioned me about ops in the past. I'll do some more testing and reading, and try to amend the plot by adding comparisons of methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I followed the code from [`bpy.data.objects.new`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.types.BlendDataObjects.html?highlight=objects.new#bpy.types.BlendDataObjects.new) and will put this here.

## Call Hierarchy

```c
rna_Main_objects_new               /* called by python - bpy.data.objects.new */
    BKE_object_add_only_object     /* set default values for the object */
        BKE_libblock_alloc         /* allocate memory for the object */
            new_id                 /* name validation - fallback, not \0, utf8 */
                check_for_dupid    /* check for collisions and find new name*/
                    is_dupid       /* linear search for duplicate name */
                id_sort_by_name    /* sort list */
```

## Links

- [`rna_Main_objects_new`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_main_api.c#l171)
- [`BKE_object_add_only_object`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/object.c#l973)
- [`BKE_libblock_alloc`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/library.c#l764)
- [`new_id`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/library.c#l1352)
- [`check_for_dupid`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/library.c#l1238)
- [`id_sort_by_name`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/library.c#l1182)

## Condensed body of `new_id`

```c
bool new_id(ListBase *lb, ID *id, const char *tname)
{
    bool result;
    char name[MAX_ID_NAME - 2];

    BLI_strncpy(name, tname, sizeof(name));

    result = check_for_dupid(lb, id, name);
    strcpy(id->name + 2, name);

    /* however all data in blender should be sorted, not just duplicate names
     * sorting should not hurt, but noting just incase it alters the way other
     * functions work, so sort every time */

    id_sort_by_name(lb, id);

    return result;
}
```

## Body of `is_dupid` called in `check_for_dupid`

```c
static ID *is_dupid(ListBase *lb, ID *id, const char *name)
{
    ID *idtest = NULL;

    for (idtest = lb->first; idtest; idtest = idtest->next) {
        /* if idtest is not a lib */ 
        if (id != idtest && idtest->lib == NULL) {
            /* do not test alphabetic! */
            /* optimized */
            if (idtest->name[2] == name[0]) {
                /* STREQ - macro for strcmp */
                if (STREQ(name, idtest->name + 2)) break;
            }
        }
    }

    return idtest;
}
```

## Body of `id_sort_by_name`

```c
void id_sort_by_name(ListBase *lb, ID *id)
{
    ID *idtest;

    /* insert alphabetically */
    if (lb->first != lb->last) {
        BLI_remlink(lb, id);

        idtest = lb->first;
        while (idtest) {
            if (BLI_strcasecmp(idtest->name, id->name) > 0 || 
               (idtest->lib && !id->lib)) {
                BLI_insertlinkbefore(lb, idtest, id);
                break;
            }
            idtest = idtest->next;
        }
        /* as last */
        if (idtest == NULL) {
            BLI_addtail(lb, id);
        }
    }
}
```

So indeed blender checks for duplicates and furthermore removes the id from the list again and inserts it alphabetically.

You can't even trick it by choosing names in the right order `C`, `B`, `A` because `is_dupid` will search the full list regardless.

Though if you specify a non colliding name it exits `check_for_dupid` early and does not have to find a name on its own.

Additionally as others have mentioned you should [not use operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7360/2271) unless you have to and only need to create the mesh once.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7799e5f41198e41d0825

Comment: This is a model answer @pink-vertex, full of teaching and a direct answer to all aspects of the question. Thanks for taking the time to dig in and finding out what's really going on! OK I have my homework now.

Comment: I wonder who had to bright idea to sort all names but not perform a binary/heap search on the names. On the other hand you can't blame the voluntary coders for being lazy, can you - they should have left a TODO comment, nevertheless