# How to make these scripted duplivert meshes always face "out" using duplicates?

Tags: scripting, dupli-groups

How can my script ensure the dupliverted meshes on an icosphere faces, and on its vertices will all be facing "outwards". There is an [excellent answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67622/5334) that describes using a different technique using an "all-in-one" or a single multi-monkey-faced larger mesh, but that makes it more difficult to animate the shape mesh.

I'd like to understand the logic and/or math behind how `bpy.context.object.use_dupli_vertices_rotation` *actually works*. If I understand it, then I will be able to script the desired behavior in more complex situations every time without trial-and-error.

Here's an example. How can I adjust the script so that all the monkeys will reliably face "out" - in the direction of the vertex or face normals? (and which one is it exactly?)

**note:** I will not always use monkeys on icospheres - this is an abstraction. I'm working towards correctly animating this constellation of [4,425 Earth-facing satellites](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/19055/12102) where I'll have roughly eighty rotating circles with sixty "monkeys" each. However I will also be using 2D meshes in a second project (rather than circles), so I really want to understand the underlying logic/math of the orientations, both on 1D (circles) and 2D meshes.

**edit:** Here is one of the images from the linked satellite question to help illustrate why I want to learn to use dupliverts, and not create and keyframe four thousand individual "monkeys":

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

Potentially adjustable things:

```
# monkey.rotation_euler = 0, 0, pi   # ??

bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='OBJECT', keep_transform=True) # keep_transform ??

bpy.context.object.use_dupli_vertices_rotation = True  # ??
```

Ok here is a basic script:

```
import bpy, math

pi = math.pi
loco_f, loco_v = (-5, 0, 5), (+5, 0, 5)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(location=loco_f, size=4, subdivisions=2)
shape_mesh_f = bpy.context.active_object

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(location=loco_v, size=4, subdivisions=2)
shape_mesh_v = bpy.context.active_object

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(radius=1, location=loco_f)
monkey_f = bpy.context.active_object
# monkey.rotation_euler = 0, 0, pi

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(radius=1, location=loco_v)
monkey_v = bpy.context.active_object
# monkey.rotation_euler = 0, 0, pi

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

monkey_f.select = True 
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = shape_mesh_f

bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='OBJECT', keep_transform=True)
bpy.context.object.dupli_type = 'FACES'
bpy.context.object.use_dupli_vertices_rotation = True

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

monkey_v.select = True 
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = shape_mesh_v

bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type='OBJECT', keep_transform=True) 
bpy.context.object.dupli_type = 'VERTS'
bpy.context.object.use_dupli_vertices_rotation = True
```