# Make a sphere of cubes in Blender using python script

Tags: python

Having trouble running code on Blender.  What this code is supposed to do is make a sphere of cubes.  It can make a circle just fine but is having troubles with the embedded while loop.  It runs through the inner loop fine and makes a circle (of radius 0), but does not go through the "phi" while loop to make a sphere.[image: circle of 8 cubes a distance RadDist above the cursor and RadDist*sin(phi) = 0]

```
import bpy
from bpy import context 
from math import sin, cos, radians

cubeobject = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add

#get the cursor location in the scene
cursor = context.scene.cursor_location

#increase the radial distance of cubes in loop
RadDist = 5.0


#initialize some variables
xsize = 1.0
ysize = 1.0
zsize = 1.0
phi = 0
theta = 0.0
RadStep = 6.28/8.0
while phi < 3.14:
    while theta < 6.28:
        x = cursor.x + RadDist*cos(theta)*sin(phi+3.14/2)
        y = cursor.y + RadDist*sin(theta)*sin(phi+(3.14/2))
        z = cursor.z + RadDist*cos(phi)
        cubeobject(location = (x,y,z))
        #add cubes along the radial
        theta += RadStep
    #add cubes along the azimuthal    
    phi += RadStep   

theta = 0.0
phi = 0.0
```

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33542/how-to-make-a-mesh-surface-that-looks-like-cubes-stacked-in-the-shape-of-a-spher

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the solution.  The issue was that once i got out of the embedded while loop the theta value remained at 6.28 instead of returning to 0.0  it was remedied by putting theta = 0.0 in the outer while loop.

**lesson of the day** When you leave a while loop the values you have made remain the same when you leave, remember to reinitialize them.

here is my sphere of cubes.[image: Sphere of cubes]